# Fill rows between start and end dates in existing table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with data as below

[image: current table schema]

For each ID in the ID column, there are multiple dates for which there is an entry in the Movement_Val column. However, there are many dates in between that are not listed and where there is no value for the Movement_Val column.

I am required to add one row per date between the startdate (min(day)) and enddate (max(day)). If a value exists in the Movement_Val column for the given date, it is to be populated as it is. If no value present, I need to fill Movement_val with 0 for that date and ID.

The resulting table will look something like this
[image: expected outcome]

how can I achieve this outcome?

Comment: Can you please add how you would like to see your output.

Comment: Thanks @akshindesnowflake! I have edited the original post to include the expected output. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a calendar table from which you select all dates between min(day) and max(day). You cross join the list of dates with a list of distinct IDs, giving you a row for each combination of date and ID. Then you left join your data table to the cross join, and output movement_val if it exists or 0 otherwise. Here is an example:

```
with calendar as (
select dateadd(DAY, row_number() over(order by null) - 1, '2020-01-01'::date) as cal_date
from table(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 365))
),
movement_values as (
select 44026 as ID, '2020-07-16'::DATE as DAY, 104.19 as movement_val union all
select 13066 as ID, '2020-07-16'::DATE as DAY, 173.87 as movement_val union all
select 10794 as ID, '2020-07-17'::DATE as DAY, 3.81 as movement_val
)
select C.cal_date, ID_values.ID, nvl(M.movement_val, 0) as movement_val
from calendar C
cross join (select distinct ID from movement_values) ID_values
left join movement_values M on M.DAY = C.cal_date and M.ID = ID_values.ID
;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I shall try this out. 

What would I need to do if I need to pick the start and end dates from the existing table itself (and not specify the start date and the rowcount explicitly as in the above example), and use that here? Also, because the actual table itself contains about 180000 rows, it might not be possible to do a select on each row as shown in the example. How should I handle that? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "because the actual table itself contains about 180000 rows, it might not be possible to do a select on each row". I assume you already have a table that is populated and you would substitute the table name instead of movement_values that I used as CTE in the example.

Comment: You could rewrite your calendar CTE something like this:
##
select dateadd(DAY, row_number() over(order by null) - 1, '2020-01-01'::date) as cal_date
from table(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 365))
qualify cal_date between (select min(day) from movement_values) and (select max(day) from movement_values)
##
Again, you would substitute the name of your actual table for movement_values. In the generator part you would ensure that you cover all dates in your time range.

Comment: Maja: Thanks a lot again - I adopted your new suggestion for the calendar CTE and was able to get the expected result using it! Thanks very much!